# Box-shadow in the end of ifined block. Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got fixed block with scroll and when I scroll to the end of the block, the button should have a shadow. What are heights we need to be compared here?

```js
function scrollButtonShadow() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $('.button').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
        } else {
            $('.button').css('box-shadow', 'none');
        }
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', scrollButtonShadow);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ececec;
  position: fixed;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi nihil magni placeat ducimus optio cupiditate sequi deleniti dolorem minus suscipit exercitationem fuga doloribus ipsa libero itaque dicta, error esse, nulla laudantium magnam officia tempore asperiores? Autem exercitationem nihil saepe hic laboriosam quos rerum id quod beatae natus cumque, ducimus eligendi dolores voluptas labore delectus nisi quidem culpa. Ad aperiam laboriosam inventore nisi accusamus, cum, voluptate tenetur. Facilis ratione maiores quibusdam consequuntur velit illo sit explicabo voluptates minus perspiciatis voluptatem optio commodi quos sint eligendi, beatae ipsa, et nam cupiditate at ducimus, ad accusantium sed. Iure repellendus deserunt veniam fugiat amet, sed aliquam ducimus labore necessitatibus ipsum odit voluptatem dicta sit voluptatum tempore possimus a? Ullam recusandae praesentium qui dolor officiis magni et molestiae quidem dolores dolorum animi repellat, iste, dolorem similique! Voluptate labore ipsam delectus totam, dolorum adipisci dolores, corporis amet repellendus iure animi. Vero eveniet eius dolore tempora, soluta explicabo ut, qui esse commodi, fuga debitis. Facilis tempora dolorum commodi in nesciunt culpa placeat praesentium, quis dignissimos ea asperiores ut omnis adipisci vero dolore aliquid architecto est quo, necessitatibus. 
        <div class="button"><button>Click</button></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what `jq` tag for?

Comment: Why do you wrap a button style around that button? Better add your box shadow to the button directly and remove the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you must add a paragraph tag (i.e. `<p>`) to calculate width of scrolled block:

```
<div class="block">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi nihil magni placeat ducimus optio cupiditate sequi deleniti dolorem minus suscipit exercitationem fuga doloribus ipsa libero itaque dicta, error esse, nulla laudantium magnam officia tempore asperiores? Autem exercitationem nihil saepe hic laboriosam quos rerum id quod beatae natus cumque, ducimus eligendi dolores voluptas labore delectus nisi quidem culpa. Ad aperiam laboriosam inventore nisi accusamus, cum, voluptate tenetur. Facilis ratione maiores quibusdam consequuntur velit illo sit explicabo voluptates minus perspiciatis voluptatem optio commodi quos sint eligendi, beatae ipsa, et nam cupiditate at ducimus, ad accusantium sed. Iure repellendus deserunt veniam fugiat amet, sed aliquam ducimus labore necessitatibus ipsum odit voluptatem dicta sit voluptatum tempore possimus a? Ullam recusandae praesentium qui dolor officiis magni et molestiae quidem dolores dolorum animi repellat, iste, dolorem similique! Voluptate labore ipsam delectus totam, dolorum adipisci dolores, corporis amet repellendus iure animi. Vero eveniet eius dolore tempora, soluta explicabo ut, qui esse commodi, fuga debitis. Facilis tempora dolorum commodi in nesciunt culpa placeat praesentium, quis dignissimos ea asperiores ut omnis adipisci vero dolore aliquid architecto est quo, necessitatibus. 
        </p>
  <div class="button"><button>Click</button></div>
</div>
```

In script:

```
function scrollButtonShadow(event) {
    var blockScrool = $(this).scrollTop();
    var blockHeight = $(this).find('p').height() + $(this).find('div').height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    var delta = blockHeight - windowHeight - blockScrool;
    if (delta < 0) {
        $('.button').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
    } else {
        $('.button').css('box-shadow', 'none');
    }
}
```